# ¿Cómo obtener datos en un cambio de período SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando cambio de periodo de meses para eso estoy utlizando SQL Server en un procedimiento almacenado.

Les comento mas o menos lo que estoy haciendo:

En una tabla llamada `TTareasIngreso_New` están todos los servicios que van ser pagados (agua, luz, internet, cable, etc). Éstos recibos siempre se van a pagar de manera mensual, ya que cada vez que yo page, al campo `fechaPago` se le suma un mes más y los demás datos (monto, número de boucher pagado, fecha real de pago). Dicho servicio se encuentra en la tabla `TTareasAtender`

Pues ahora quiero que cuando, por ejemplo , todo los servicios que tengo que cancelar este mes (05 / Mayo)  y yo escoja un mes distinto, por ejemplo **Junio** , a mayo , automáticamente todos esos registros deben decir **Junio** pero cuando yo filtre los registros de mayo, esos registros que yo registre con mes distinto al actual, deben aparecer.

Es decir, si existe ese mes que ya se registro aparezca y si no existe que todo los registro sean de ese mes que se escogió.

Para eso estoy realizando este *Stored Procedure* pero cuando lo ejecuto los datos se borran:

```
--EXEC BuscarRegistro '2017-09-01'
ALTER PROCEDURE BuscarRegistro @date AS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM TTareasAtender
            WHERE montopagado IS NOT NULL
                AND month(fechacumplimientooriginal) = month(@date)
            )
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        INTO #Temp1
        FROM TTareasAtender
        WHERE month(fechacumplimientooriginal) = month(@date)

        SELECT *
        INTO #Temp2
        FROM TTareasIngreso_New
        WHERE month(fechacumplimiento) = month(@date)

        DROP TABLE TTareasAtender

        DROP TABLE TTareasIngreso_New

        SELECT *
        INTO TTareasAtender
        FROM #Temp1

        SELECT *
        INTO TTareasIngreso_New
        FROM #Temp2

        SELECT *
        FROM TTareasAtender

        SELECT *
        FROM TTareasIngreso_New
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        INTO #Temp3
        FROM TTareasAtender

        SELECT *
        INTO #Temp4
        FROM TTareasIngreso_New

        UPDATE a
        SET a.fechacumplimiento = b.fechacumplimiento
            ,UsuarioAtencion = NULL
            ,EstadoTiempo = NULL
            ,fechaemision = NULL
            ,IDEstadoTarea = 3
            ,comentario = NULL
        FROM #temp4 a
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT idregistrotareas
                ,(DATEADD(Month, 1, FechacumplimientoOriginal)) AS 'fechacumplimiento'
            FROM #temp3
            ) b ON a.idregistrotareas = b.idregistrotareas

        SELECT *
        FROM #Temp4

        SELECT *
        FROM #Temp3
    END
END
```

**Esta es mi tabla TTAREASATENDER**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esta es mi tabla TTareasIngreso_New**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no me queda claro el problema... no se agregan los registros de meses posteriores?

Comment: @gbianchi exacto mi amigo no se agregan los meses posteriores es decir si pongo del otro mes todo deben estar del otro mes pero cuando vuelvo a poner del mes que se registro el monto,recibo,etc sale en blanco y no recupera los datos que ya se han registrado no se si me explico.
Pues la logica solo debe ser que si yo escogo un mes que no he registrado que todo se ponga los meses que yo he eligido pero si yo escogo un mes que ya se registro y tiene datos que me muestre todo con esos datos de ese mes .

Comment: ok sigo sin entender mucho pq es dificil seguir tu SP.. pero estas borrando tablas y recreandolas, lo cual puede provocar lo que me estas contando.. tenes una especie de lio ahi...

Comment: entonces como podria hacer sin borrar las tablas esque estaba borrando las tablas cuando es un mes diferente que yo escogo yo nunca habria realizado algo como cambio de periodo creo que es algo avanzado @gbianchi

Comment: @gbianchi entonces no tendria que eliminar ningun tabla